# Android PullToRefresh library clipping view issue in PullToRefreshScrollView

Tags: android

[Video of the issue here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxtZzw32r5s)

[Link to the library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh)

The video might be a little hard to see, but what is happening is the content in the ScrollView is clipping strangely when I add a new fragment to the Activity. Instead of smoothly animating down, creates an extra margin of about 55 px (on a 720 x 1280 phone), then corrects itself once the animation completes.

I dug around the source code and found that if I comment these two methods out of the onSizeChanged() method of the PullToRefreshBase class, the animations will work correctly:

```
@Override
protected final void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    if (DEBUG) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format("onSizeChanged. W: %d, H: %d", w, h));
    }

    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    //TODO both of these methods below combined cause the glitchy issue

    // We need to update the header/footer when our size changes
    refreshLoadingViewsSize();

    // Update the Refreshable View layout
    refreshRefreshableViewSize(w, h);

    //TODO both of these methods above combined cause the glitchy issue

    /**
     * As we're currently in a Layout Pass, we need to schedule another one
     * to layout any changes we've made here
     */
    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            requestLayout();
        }
    });
}
```

The refreshLoadingViewsSize() and refreshRefreshableViewSize() methods are what cause the problem, together. But, when I comment them out, the PullToRefresh functionality doesn't work anymore. This is because the first method, which sets the header size, isn't being called. This means the header height is always 0, which breaks the pulldown functionality, which relies on the height of the header to work. Furthermore the header itself won't even show up, and that doesn't work.

Commenting just one out will make the clipping problem even worse, unfortunately.

I also tried a hacky fix, where I run those two methods only on the first call of onSizeChanged, and ignore them afterwards. Like this:

```
if(mFirstGo) {
    // We need to update the header/footer when our size changes
    refreshLoadingViewsSize();

    // Update the Refreshable View layout
    refreshRefreshableViewSize(w, h);

    mFirstGo = false;
}
```

This works great except for one problem. When the fragment is added, the padding is incorrectly set so that the content of the ScrollView is higher than it should be. This is because the padding is set the first time, but then is never reset again. It's like if the padding is 0 the entire time that isn't a problem, but if it is set at first, it needs to continue to be reset each time the view size changes.

I think the cause of this issue is the padding change happening independently of the view change, but I'm not exactly sure. If anyone has some insight here I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!